# Dailymotion embed: foreground and background parameters not working?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I'm trying to change the the foreground and background colors of an embedded Dailymotion video like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xjo5zb?background=0000FF&foreground=00FF00&highlight=FF0000" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The values for `foreground` and `background` don't have any effect. I also noted that choosing a dark(er) color for `highlight` changes the background color to light grey.

Using just one or two of the parameters doesn't make any difference.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

you are right, these parameters (`foreground` and `background`) have been deprecated in dailymotion new player. They don't have any effect on the player skin any more. 
Also, you are still right, skin colors are automatically adjusted (dark or clear) based on the `highlight` color.

The documentation will be fixed very soon regarding those changes.